# Color the Non selected tabs in a QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qtstylesheets, qtabwidget

[image]

In a 3-tab QTabWidget, I would like to change the background color of the NON-SELECTED tabs, leaving the selected tab in the default background color (white).  In other words, I want to change the color of the small part of the two non-selected tabs that shows above the selected tab.

I've looked all around this site and have found tid bits of code, but I cannot translate them into the format I need. So far,I have this in the init of my program, but it is incomplete and does not work.

```
self.ui.tabWidget.tabBar().setStyleSheet('xxxxxxxx {background-color: yellow }')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `QTabBar::tab:!selected`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()

    # For more information to customize the QTabWidget and QTabBar check
    # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar
    w.setStyleSheet(
        """
    QTabBar::tab:!selected {
        background: green
    }
    """
    )
    for i in range(5):
        w.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(), f"tab-{i}")
    w.show()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In your case:

```
self.ui.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("""QTabBar::tab:!selected{ background: green }""")
```

Comment: Can you put the answer in the format that I need and understand, like my example in my question?  I cannot translate your "QTabBar::tab:!slected ..."  thanks

Comment: @Dennis I provide a MWE for the community to understand how to use it, but if you still do not understand I have placed the code for your particular code

Comment: thank you.  One last thing: my tabs are angled (done in QTDesigner), and the green color goes outside the boundaries of the angled tab.  Any way to make the color conform to the shape of the tab?  If not, no bid deal.

Comment: @Dennis provide a [MRE] and a picture of what you get

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to paste an image here to show you.  However, in QtCreator/designer, on the right under QTabWidget, there are 2 options for the shape of the tab -- rounded and triangular.  I choose triangular.  The selected tab shows with dog-eared edges, and the green color on the non-selected tabs is square.

Comment: @Dennis Do not put the image in the comments but you have to edit your question and there provide everything I have asked you

Comment: It's at the top